# StringTemplate4 - Storing attribute value in variable

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I am injecting an attribute into my StringTemplate4 template which has multiple levels of sub-attributes.

As I work through the template outputting various elements of it I need to refer to attributes quite far down in the nesting at differing points, leading to the template quite often doing multiple references such as...

***attribute.subattribute.subattribute2.finalattribute1***
***attribute.subattribute.subattribute2.finalattribute2***

Is there a way in StringTemplate4 to store the subattribute2 in a "Variable" that I could then refer to instead to tidy up the logic somewhat?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Assignment [isn't supported](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/db3f2274a0b7a3aec917aedde12ec2991068431f/doc/motivation.md) in StringTemplate

Comment: That's a shame thanks for the response and the link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper template:

```
foo(attribute) ::= <<
<helper(attribute.subattribute.subattribute2)>
>>

helper(sub) ::= <<
<sub.finalattribute1>
<sub.finalattribute2>
>>
```